# Redisson 3.16.2 Unsupported protocol version 0

Tags: redisson

I'm using Redisson 3.16.2 on my prodcution environment and getting "Unsupported protocol version 0" error. On test environment, I didn't get this error. What does this error mean?

Here is stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 0
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.start(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1375)
    at org.redisson.codec.MarshallingCodec.lambda$new$0(MarshallingCodec.java:145)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:366)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:183)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:122)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Make sure that data stored the same MarshallingCodec codec.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with version 3.14.0.

SOLUTION:

- I updated the version to 3.16.3.
- I deleted the old cached values.

EXPLANATION:

The version should not be the problem itself, but the cached data (in my case) was loaded with another version of reddis and this caused the error. Updating to the latest version is still recommended.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because default codec has changed since 3.13.0 version to MarshallingCodec. Previously it was FstCodec. So data stored with previous codec can't be read with MarshallingCodec

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Codec:

```
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:16379");
    config.setCodec(new StringCodec());
    RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```